# Trying to change python2 to python3 on the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was trying to install a new module when the problem appears. I was trying to use `python3` but still have python 2.7 version. I've changed to `/bin/zsh` in the settings. Tried `brew install python3`. Finally, I've came with `sudo update-alternatives--setpython/usr/local/bin/python3`, but I couldn't type my password, as I was trying to type symbols, nothing happens.I see only a key near the password line(can't show it). Nothing registered. Like my keyword is broken or something. I am using MacOs Catalina. I will be very grateful if you you help.

```
Last login: Mon Aug 17 13:24:33 on ttys000
rs@Arinas-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo update-alternatives--setpython/usr/local/bin/python3
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

Comment: First of all, seems you fail at your password here. Second, I think `update-alternatives` is a linux command, that won't work for OSX.

Comment: Also, passwords don't appear, but the characters still get registered.

Comment: Type `which python3` to check if it's installed. If it is, then you can just start using `python3`. If it's not installed, `brew install python` will install the latest version of Python, which would then be accessible using `python3`.

Comment: I used it. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Typing in the password happens without visual feedback
With Homebrew you can try this:

```
$ brew install pyenv
```

Then install the latest Python3 version and set it for your zsh:

```
$ pyenv install 3.8.5
$ pyenv global 3.8.5
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
$ python -V
```

Comment: still no answer.(

Comment: in a macOS Terminal, type or paste: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` or what is your problem now?

Comment: Now I have 'dquote'